# How to add an extra label in a multiselect component in PrimeNg?

Tags: angular, typescript, label, multi-select

I have a multiselect primeNg component which is fiiling dinamicaly after a server request:

```
<p-multiSelect
    [options]="multiselectDisplayOptions"
    [(ngModel)]="selectedValues"
    [optionLabel]="columnToDisplay.reference"
    [selectionLimit]="selectedLimitOne"
    display="chip"
    [showHeader]=false
    (onChange)="onChange($event.value)"
    (onClick)="onClick()"
    appendTo="body"
    [required]="isRequired">
</p-multiSelect>
```

In the main component, I have data binding for these @Input()s, and I want to choose "All sites" from here: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXKxH.png)

and the last option should be "All Sites" without select all sites from the multi-select component. The option "All Sites" won't be a record in the database.

Comment: What version of primeng are you using?

Comment: @R.Richards primeng version 11.4.0

Comment: Do you have `showToggleAll` turned off (set to false) in your display options? Enabling that may give you the functionality you would like.

Comment: Right, it's working, but i did't want that. I need to have an extra option which has the name All Sites like : Site 1, site 2, Site 3 and All Sites, and when I choose All sites, the other three option must be disable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is my example, use this and adapt styles and logic for youself:

What to look for:

1. named your multiselect `#multiselect`
2. set `[filter]="false" [showToggleAll]="false"` to remove base input and checkbox
3. in content of multiselect use `<ng-template>` to customize it
4. in `<ng-template pTemplate="header">` add logic for custom checkbox `<p-checkbox (onChange)="multiselect.allChecked ? multiselect.uncheckAll() : multiselect.checkAll()"></p-checkbox>`

HTML:

```
<p-multiSelect #multiselect [filter]="false" [showToggleAll]="false" [options]="countries" [(ngModel)]="selectedCountries" defaultLabel="Select a Country" optionLabel="name" class="multiselect-custom">
    <ng-template pTemplate="header">
      <p-checkbox (onChange)="multiselect.allChecked ? multiselect.uncheckAll() : multiselect.checkAll()"></p-checkbox>
      All countries
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template let-value pTemplate="selectedItems">
      <div class="country-item country-item-value" *ngFor="let option of selectedCountries">
        <div>{{option.name}}</div>
      </div>
      <div *ngIf="!selectedCountries || selectedCountries.length === 0" class="country-placeholder">
        Select Countries
      </div>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template let-country pTemplate="item">
      <div class="country-item">
        <div>{{country.name}}</div>
      </div>
    </ng-template>
  </p-multiSelect>
```

TS:

```
countries: Country[];

  selectedCountries: Country[] = [];

  constructor() {
    this.countries = [
      {name: 'Australia', code: 'AU'},
      {name: 'Brazil', code: 'BR'},
      {name: 'China', code: 'CN'},
      {name: 'Egypt', code: 'EG'},
      {name: 'France', code: 'FR'},
      {name: 'Germany', code: 'DE'},
      {name: 'India', code: 'IN'},
      {name: 'Japan', code: 'JP'},
      {name: 'Spain', code: 'ES'},
      {name: 'United States', code: 'US'}
    ];
  }
```